# display:none not removed on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototypejs

I have a strange problem.

I'm using Protoype to show a `"<ul></ul>"` markup with Show() method (Toggle() too).

When I click on my button to display my `"<ul></ul>"`, Internet Explorer display it on the screen, but in the source code, the `"display:none"` is always present O_o

And my flash player doesn't work because of this.

But on other browers, it works

You can see it here (click on "Voir la réponse vidéo")

http://www.snaaf.fr/question

Comment: Is Ie throwing any script errors?

Comment: I don't understand the question: The source code will not change because of the toggle. What is the problem? Why does your Flash player not work?

Comment: I dont't know how to explain the problem, but on IE, the display:none attribute is not removed, but it's still displayed on the screen

Comment: Try it on IE et Firefox, you will see the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour. The source code is the source code, not a live representation of the DOM. If you want that, use a DOM inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a button that in a dual use popup div.
Seems to be an issue with IE and I sorted it by adding a position:relative to the element with the display:none.

Just another one of those darn IE css quirks.